# Use of CASE with criteria from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have to do a select query to create a view with specific criteria.

I have multiple tables which contains many many columns and lines.

However, I have extracted a value to use as my key (e.g.: id). I have 7000+ of those unique keys that I extracted from all my tables with the function UNION to avoid duplicates.

Now, I want to add a column INDICATOR_1 which will affect the value YES or NO based on criteria.

This is where I struggle.

I need to find the line in those tables that contain the id. After that, I'd like to check, always in that line, if the field XYZ contains the value 'N' (example). If yes, affect the value 'YES' to INDICATOR_1, else it's no.

In a matter of pseudo-code, what I want to do looks like this :

```
CASE
    WHEN id = (id from table_1) AND (if table_1.xyz = 'N') 
       THEN 'YES'
       ELSE 'NO'
END AS INDICATOR_1
```

I don't know if I'm clear enough, but your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database table would really help.

Comment: In what scenario would ID be different from ID from table_1?  It just looks like you want `case when tabl_1.xyz = 'N' then 'YES' else 'NO' end`.

Comment: Or perhaps `case when (select xyz from table_1 where id=tablealias.id) = 'N' then 'YES' else 'NO' end`  I'm not sure what your tablealias is in the rest of your query because you don't provide any code for us to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a separate indicator for each table.  Something like this:

```
select i.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table1 t1
                          where t1.id = i.id and t1.xyz = 'N'
                         )
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as indicator_1,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table2 t2
                          where t2.id = i.id and t2.xyz = 'N'
                         )
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as indicator_2,
       . . .
from (<your id list here>) i
```

Comment: Not exactly. Let's say that I have 2 tables, I want to indicate 'YES' if those criterias matches :

table1 : field1= 'N'
and
table2 : field2= 'N'

Comment: In other words, is there a way in your "case when exists (...)) to add a logical operator. Like this :

case when exists (....) OR (.....) then 'YES' else 'NO' ?

Comment: @Provost . . . Your question seems to be asking for a separate indicator per table.  Of course, you can combine the `exists` conditions using `and`/`or` if you want logic that spans tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fix this in the union, where you have all the data you need. You probably have something like:

```
SELECT Id
FROM table_1

UNION

SELECT Id
FROM table_2
```

How about selecting the information you want as well (I use `distinct` here to clarify):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
,      CASE WHEN table_1.xyz = 'N' THEN 'N' 
            ELSE 'Y' 
       END INDICATOR_1
FROM   table_1
```

This can lead to more records than you had, if id's can have records of both flavours exist. We can fix that with a row number in an outer query. You end up with something like:

```
SELECT Id
,      INDICATOR_1
FROM   (
         SELECT Id
         ,      INDICATOR_1
         ,      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN INDICATOR_1 ='N' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) RN
         FROM   (
                  SELECT Id
                  ,      CASE WHEN table_1.xyz = 'N' THEN 'N' 
                              ELSE 'Y' 
                         END INDICATOR_1
                  FROM   table_1
                  UNION
                  ... 
                ) T
       ) S
WHERE S.RN = 1
```

You can in fact shorten that by using the inner most case expression in the ROW_NUMBER expression.